# In vim, is there a way to set "very magic" permanently and globally?

Tags: vim

I use "very magic" for regexp searches (i.e. /\v or %s/\v) but I wish I could set some option so I don't have to include \v anymore, anywhere. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Not directly, however you can always use a mapping:

```
:nnoremap / /\v
:cnoremap %s/ %s/\v
```

Even if you could set 'very magic' in the way you can `set nomagic`, you really wouldn't want to as it would break pretty much every plugin in existence.

**Edit**

See also [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions).

Comment: +1 Thanks. FWIW, this seems more general purpose: `:cnoremap s/ s/\v`.

Comment: @FMc That can cause problems when you're searching for a pattern that ends in 's'.

Comment: I couldn't care less about plugins.  I want regular expressions that don't suck.

Comment: Do **not** use the second one. It means typing `:%s//replace` to replace your last search (the workflow suggested in Practical Vim) will replace it with `:%s/\v` when you type, so you'll have to erase the `\v`, which is a big setback

Comment: @DrAl, regarding your final comment, it seems like there should be a way to change that setting without affecting plugins.  not saying you're wrong, but it seems like an obvious feature: when *I* search, I want things to always work this way -- and that should have no effect on plugins.

Comment: @Jonah I couldn't agree more, but as far as I know, there isn't a way.

Comment: @DrAl Well, doesn't the difference between `magic` and `nomagic` aso affect plugins, thus making your last comment no so significant? Plus, plugins can use `\v`, `\m`, `\M`, and `\V` as needed, right?

Comment: @trusktr I think the point was that if you decide to set very magic, existing plugins that don't use `\m` etc would stop working.  @Jonah's point was that this is slightly daft behaviour and plugins should work independently of "UI" settings.

Comment: On plugins, I wonder how many plugins use the practice of appending all their searches with `\v`, `\m` etc. to make all their searches independent of user settings?

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible (in the current or a future version of vim) to have a setting that applies only interactively and doesn't affect plugins.

Comment: @KeithThompson That would certainly be nice.

Answer (score 16):

EDIT2: I just discovered this plugin, which may be better than the remapping solutions (which seem to have some unavoidable drawbacks; see below). I haven't tested it yet, though, so I don't know if it behaves exactly as desired.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4849

EDIT3: I've been using the plugin for about a year and a half, and I love it. It still interferes with search history, however (see below), and it also breaks `incsearch`, so I have the following in my Vim config:

```
" Since I use incsearch:
let g:VeryMagic = 0
nnoremap / /\v
nnoremap ? ?\v
vnoremap / /\v
vnoremap ? ?\v
" If I type // or ??, I don't EVER want \v, since I'm repeating the previous
" search.
noremap // //
noremap ?? ??
" no-magic searching
noremap /v/ /\V
noremap ?V? ?\V

" Turn on all other features.
let g:VeryMagicSubstituteNormalise = 1
let g:VeryMagicSubstitute = 1
let g:VeryMagicGlobal = 1
let g:VeryMagicVimGrep = 1
let g:VeryMagicSearchArg = 1
let g:VeryMagicFunction = 1
let g:VeryMagicHelpgrep = 1
let g:VeryMagicRange = 1
let g:VeryMagicEscapeBackslashesInSearchArg = 1
let g:SortEditArgs = 1
```

---

I used DrAI's suggestion for a while, but found it frustrating in practice because of the following behavior:

If you type the following:
    /{pattern}
    :%s//{replacement}

...then, without this mapping, you can see what you're about to replace before you do a replacement. But with the remapping, you suddenly have `s/\v/` instead of `s//`; this matches **eveything in the file**, which is obviously wrong.

Fortunately, the `s` command itself has an alternative form that uses `very magic` for its search. So here are the mappings I'm currently using in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
cnoremap %s/ %smagic/
cnoremap >s/ >smagic/ 
nnoremap :g/ :g/\v
nnoremap :g// :g//
```

Note that just mapping `s/` leads to problems when attempting to use a pattern that ends in `s`; similarly, mapping `g/` would create problems when using patterns ending in `g`. Note that the `:g/` and `:g//` mappings prevent Vim from showing the command immediately.

EDIT: Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a "magic" version of `:global`, which is why the seemingly-superfluous mapping of `:g//` is used to ensure that the global command can use the previous search pattern.

Another drawback is that these remappings interfere with search history. As an example, consider using `*` to search for the next occurrence of the word under the cursor. This causes Vim to search for the pattern `\<[word]\>`, which does **not** start with `\v`. Without the remappings described above, typing `/` and pressing the up arrow will recall that search pattern. **With** the remappings, however, after typing `/`, you must delete the automatically-inserted `\v` before pressing the up arrow in order to recall that pattern.

Comment: `cnoremap >s/ >smagic/` doesn't seem to work when I select a visual range. I also tried escaping the bracket to `cnoremap \>s/ \>smagic/` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @DaveKennedy Have you tried the plugin? It's much more reliable for me; I've had very few issues with it. I no longer use the mappings listed in that second code-block.

Answer (score 1):

To reply to [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23021259/7129538) as I can't comment yet, from [How to make substitute() use another magic mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/how-to-make-substitute-use-another-magic-mode), the vim docs and my own testing, `smagic` (and `sm`) only enters `magic` mode and not `very magic` mode.

```
                        *:snomagic* *:sno*
:[range]sno[magic] ...  Same as `:substitute`, but always use 'nomagic'.
            {not in Vi} 

                        *:smagic* *:sm*
:[range]sm[agic] ...    Same as `:substitute`, but always use 'magic'.
            {not in Vi}
```

For example, one should `(`'s turn into `)`'s in a file with `:%sm/(/)/g` and not `:%sm/\(/\)/g`, which shows the following for me

```
E54: Unmatched \(
E54: Unmatched \(
E476: Invalid command
```

Instead, to enter `very magic` mode, one should use `\v` in the search expression of `substitute` (i.e. `:%s/\v\(/\)/g`)
(Please correct me if I've messed up, I am quite new to Vim)

Answer (score 0):

https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html#magic

> Add a normal mode mapping that will automatically insert the `\v` for you whenever you begin a search

my current config in init.vim:
(I want to go to the fist line and then search, and return back using `'s`, so `msgg`)

```
" vim has set:  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ahk  setf autohotkey
if &filetype == 'vim'
    nnoremap / msgg/\v^[^"]*
elseif &filetype == 'autohotkey'
    echo 'ahk'
    nnoremap / msgg/\v^[^;]*
    " todo 
    " https://github.com/hnamikaw/vim-autohotkey
elseif expand('%:t') == 'wf_key.ahk'
    nnoremap / msgg/\v^[^;]*

elseif &filetype  == 'zsh'
    nnoremap / msgg/\v^[^#]*
else
    " vscode neovim can not detect filetype?
    nnoremap / msgg/\v^[^#";(//)(/*)]*
endif

nnoremap ? msgg/\v
" nnoremap / /\v
cnoremap s/ s/\v
```

todo:  plugin for `very magic`
https://github.com/coot/EnchantedVim