# List of all regex implementations?

Tags: regex, programming-languages

Is there a list of Regex implementations on the web, showing their differences / similarities?

For exaple, Emacs elisp Regex is different to JavaScript or Perl regex, not to mention all the different implementations used by different editor software,

e.g. VS2010 uses `{}` instead of `()` to group expressions for back references.

Once upon a time I could rely on a Regex conversion list in O'Reilly's Regex Pocket Quick Reference, but something online would be so much easier, and complete.

By the way, I am aware of (of course) http://www.regular-expressions.info/ which is good, but no where near complete.

I'll compile a list from the answers posted here, and anything else I can find.

### Variations

#### General Variations

The differences in implementations are usually the way special characters `{}()[]^$` are handled (escaping rules etc.), and occasionally substituted; the handling/availability of POSIX character classes e.g. `[:digit:]`, and the use of options, e.g. `g` `i` etc.

(a work in progress, if you know any caveats, differences for these implementations please add them as an answer)

- ActionScript - uses ECMA style
- Delphi (.Net) - Uses .Net style. Delphi Win32 has no native regex, but PCRE wrappers are available.
- Emacs/ELisp - has 2 different contexts, escaping uses `\\` in elisp, and `\` in `regexp-replace`. Special chars `(){}[]` are escaped when using them for regex features, much like `sed`.
- Eclipse - Search uses Java style regex.
- GNU (Linux) - POSIX BRE / ERE
- Grep - POSIX BRE / ERE
- Groovy - Uses Java style.
- IntelliJ
- Java - Java style.
- JavaScript - uses ECMA style.
- NetBeans
- .NET - Uses the classes in System.Text.RegularExpressions
- Notepad++ - PCRE
- PCRE (C/C++) - Open source library, used by many third party languages and apps. (e.g. PHP, TCL, R etc.)
- Perl - Perl style
- PHP - POSIX ERE, PCRE, (PHP5's multibyte string module uses Oniguruma)
- POSIX - BRE (Basic Regex), ERE (Extended Regex)
- PowerShell - .Net style
- Python - Python style
- R - POSIX ERE/BRE, PCRE
- REALbasic - PCRE
- Ruby - [Oniguruma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma)
- Sed - special chars `(){}[]` are escaped when using them for regex features.
- Tcl - Three flavors, Tcl ARE (advanced regex), POSIX ERE, POSIX BRE.
- TextMate - [Oniguruma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma)
- Tera Term - [Oniguruma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma)
- VBScript - ECMA
- Visual Basic 6 - ECMA (when using Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 COM object)
- Visual Studio - Grouping braces are `{}` (more details to follow.)
- wxWidgets - Tcl ARE, POSIX BRE/ERE
- XML Schema - XML
- XQuery & XPath - Xpath

### Additional references.

- **[Wikipedia's List of regular expression software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_expression_software)**
- **[Regex info's comparison of Regex flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)**

Comment: Yes, well that's very nice, however since we are in the profession of programming, we do tend to use the tools which serve us best, if I had the same level of support for .Net/C# in Emacs, that I do in VS2010, trust me, I'd be using it. But even with extensive yak shaving on my own time, that's really not about to happen, so ... you know, please :)

Comment: non-free but handy http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html

Comment: Yep, I have it for Windows, something cross platform would be good, but just the info for each implementations differences would be so useful.

Comment: Let's not forget about Vim and its own custom flavor of regexes. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [Regular Expression Flavor Comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) on [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It contains at least the nowadays most important regular expression implementations and their characteristics.

Comment: If only there was a complete and comprehensive, community resource!? :)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.regular-expressions.info is the closest thing I know to a comprehensive list (and even it is nowhere near complete). ([This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) in particular.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of libraries, languages and applications supporting regular expressions on Wikipedia which includes a feature comparison table:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Answer (score 2):

I found [this overview](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html) very useful when i get confused with the different variants.