# Tool to convert regex between different language syntaxes?

Tags: java, python, regex, perl

Is there a tool to convert a regex from one popular language's syntax to another? For example a Python-style regex to a Java-style regex?.

Or at least, has someone put together a set of rules to do these conversions?

And obviously some constructs won't be able to convert.

Comment: You could write a regex for that... :-P

Comment: @GaretJax I think the grammar for regexes is not regular, so no :)

Comment: why would he want to do that.

Comment: Regexes are no more limited to regular grammars I think; I mean, you can use callback functions in python or other special constructs which are not part of the formal definition to parse whatever you need... I have no proof of that though... ;)

Comment: @Brandon_R: mine was only a joke...

Comment: @Jörn, this is not formal language theory. Regex in Perl/Java/Python  are not regular, and I do not think they ever were.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644847/list-of-all-regex-implementations), and follow the link to "Regex info's comparison of Regex flavors", that got me to a tool called [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), which sounds like it might do what you want.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows computer but the comparison info is probably good enough to construct a translator of my own. Thanks!

Comment: For a list of alternatives to RegexBuddy, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132405/free-alternative-to-regxbuddy

Comment: Curious, did you have any success in rolling your own?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is a Windows tool that will do this: [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)