# use perl regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, perl

I am trying to use regular expressions in Java that are built for Perl's regex. My goal is to have a standardized set of regular expressions so that both our Java apps and Perl scripts are producing the same results when applying the regular expressions.

Is there a library that will take a perl regex such as: `\bbypa(s|r)?\b` and use it directly in Java or do I need to escape special characters for each regular expression?

If I have to implement the second method (which I hope I can avoid), what are the characters that need to be escaped to function in Java?

Any insight into this will be helpful

Thanks!!

EDIT:

I have over 500 of these regular expressions sitting in the database. They all work perfect on perl. Do I just need to escape the backslashes when using these regex in Java and assume it produces the same results as Perl?

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer to whether there is an open source library that converts Perl's regex to Java syntax

Comment: In a regular expression every literal `'\'` must be doubled `'\\'`. You can use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) to do this.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933891/tool-to-convert-regex-between-different-language-syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933891/tool-to-convert-regex-between-different-language-syntaxes)

Answer (score 0):

Your java regex would be,

```
"\\bbypa(s|r)?\\b"
```

You need to escape the backslash `\` one more time. Just put your perl regex into this [javaregex online checker](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) site and click on test button. You would get a pure java regex code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that expression, in Java you must double escape the backslash escape sequences.

```
 \\bbypa(s|r)?\\b
```