# Converter for SQL Regular expression to Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, scala, scala-collections

I am building an API that requires a SQL Regular expression to be converted to Java regular expression. This regex is specifically for the `REGEXP` keyword in MySQL.

My question is: is there any library or git-hub repo readily available to achieve this?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT company 
FROM business 
WHERE title REGEXP '^[ABCD]';
```

Input regex in MySQL: `^[ABCD]`
Output regex in Java: `[A-D]*`

I searched a lot over the internet, but could not find one to do this. Any suggestions how I can approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think `^[ABCD]` should be translated into `[A-D]*`? According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax, `^` means the same as in Java, `[ABCD]` is a character class which can be written the same way in Java. `[A-D]` is also legal both in Java and MySQL regexes and has the same meaning. So the translation of `^[ABCD]` is going to be... `^[ABCD]`.

Nobody is likely to write a library for translating between these two dialects in particular; for more general tools, see [Tool to convert regex between different language syntaxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933891/tool-to-convert-regex-between-different-language-syntaxes) or [Free alternative to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132405/free-alternative-to-regexbuddy).

Or you could write it yourself: the only syntax in that page which isn't supported in Java seems to be `[= =]`, which requires you to know which collation to use. So you could write a method which finds the `[= =]` parts (using regex), and replaces them with the complete equivalence class according to your desired collation. This does *not* mean that every pattern will give the same result on every string; see "Regular Expression Compatibility Considerations" at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html and "Differences with Java Regular Expressions" at http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp for the kind of issues you'd need to deal with.