# How to apply Condition in regex

Tags: python, regex

Hello i am a newbie and currently trying to learn about regex pattern by experimenting on various patterns. I tried to create the regex pattern for this url but failed. It's a pagination link of amazon.

> http://www.amazon.in/s/lp_6563520031_pg_2?rh=n%3A5866078031%2Cn%3A%215866079031%2Cn%3A6563520031&page=2s&ie=UTF8&qid=1446802571

Or

> http://www.amazon.in/Tena-Wet-Wipe-Pulls-White/dp/B001O1G242/ref=sr_1_46?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1446802608&sr=1-46

I just want to check the url by only these two things.

> 1. If the url has dp directory or product directory
> 2. If the url has query string page having any digit

I tried to create the regex pattern but failed. **I want that if the first thing is not there the regex pattern should match the second (or vice versa)**.

Here's the regex pattern I made:

```
.*\/(dp|product)\/ | .*page
```

Here is my regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/zD2gP5/1#python

Comment: Could you explain about these **three languages** tags? javascript or php or python?

Comment: @KevinGuan Oh sorry, i thought that the people there maybe knowing about regex. Should i remove them?

Comment: If you want to check only,why matching the whole input? Just check with [`\/(?:dp|product)\/|[&?]page=`](https://regex101.com/r/uQ8xZ9/1).

Comment: But there is *little* difference between their regex, are you using  php regex?

Comment: @KevinGuan Actually i am using python but i thought the regex would work same for different languages. My fault....

Comment: @stribizhev Can you post this as an answer. I wanted this one

Comment: Well, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644847/list-of-all-regex-implementations) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want to check if a string contains some pattern, you can use

```
\/(?:dp|product)\/|[&?]page=
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ8xZ9/1)

In Python, just check with `re.search`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'/(?:dp|product)/|[&?]page=')
test_str = "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...n.in/s/lp_6563520031_pg_2?rh=n%3A5866078031%2Cn%3A%215866079031%2Cn%3A6563520031&page=2s&ie=UTF8&qid=14468025716"
if p.search(test_str):
    print ("Found!")
```

Also, in Python regex patterns, there is no need to escape `/` slashes.

The regex matches two alternative subpatterns (`\/(?:dp|product)\/` and `[&?]page=`):

- `/` - a forward slash
- `(?:dp|product)` - either `dp` or `product` (without storing the capture inside the capture buffer since it is a *non*-capturing group)
- `/` - a slash
- `|` - or...
- `[&?]` - either a `&` or `?` (we check the start of a query string parameter)
- `page=` - literal sequence of symbols `page=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\/(dp|product)\/|page=(?=[^&]*\d)[^&]+
```

This would be my idea, please test it and let me know if you have question about.

Comment: Try to run this one regex101.com . Your previous query /(dp|product)/|page=(?=[^&]*\d)[^&]+. You just forget to escape the slashes. But Thanks