# Vim regex: why backslash before + and not before *

Tags: regex, vim

Is there any particular reason why in [vim search patterns](http://vimregex.com/) "1 or more" is `\+` (with backslash) and "zero or more" is `*` (without backslash)?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but I would guess that it's to do with the frequency which `*` and `+` are used in regular expressions vs. plain text.

Comment: you could `\v` to avoid some escaping

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that option. More info on `\v` http://briancarper.net/blog/448/vim-regexes-are-awesome

Answer (score 3):

In [comparison to Perl Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867250/430766) Vim simply has a couple syntactic differences, which make Vim regular expressions very similar to `sed`, where you also have to specify the Kleene-Operator with `*` and the one-or-more variation thereof with `\+`.

Comment: It's probably relevant to add that Vim's lignage makes its "different" syntax actually more chronologically "normal" (if less common) than the more common perl/PCRE syntax.