# how to escape '<' and '>' in xml tags using regular expression with vim?

Tags: python, regex, xml, vim

I am parsing a XML file with Python.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('selections.xml')
```

But when I execute it, such an`xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)`error occurred. After examining the file, I find there are too many < > in tags.
Therefore,I want to escape **<** and **>** in XML tags using regular expression.
For example, in the text tags, I want to escape the **<** and **>** outside of 'Winning 11'.

```
<writing>
    <topic id="10">I am a fun</topic>
    <date>2012-03-1</date>   
    <grade>86</grade>
    <text>
          You know he is a soccer fan,so you'd better to buy the game is <Winning 11>!
    </text>
</writing>
```

I know the escape of < and > is `&lt;` and `&gt;`. As there are too many  tags in my XML file therefore I want to use regular expression to solve it under vim.

Could anyone give me some ideas? I am a newbie in regular expression.

Comment: `:s/</&lt;/g | s/g/\&gt;/g`  on the line you want to replace `<` and `>`, you can't know which `<` or `>` is legit, then You need to go line by line

Comment: I only want to escape `<` and `>` in <text>tags. But there are thousands of <text> tags in the XML file. Isn't any method to escape all of them together using regular expression?

Comment: you can search them in vi and replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In detail:**

```
:%s/    #search and replace on all lines in file
\(      #open \1 group
<text>  #\n find <text> tag with newline at it's end
.*      #grab all text until next match
\)      #close \1  group
<       #the `<` mark we're looking for
\(      #open \2 group
.*\n    #grab all text until end of line
.*      #grab text on the next line
<\/text> #find </text> tag
\)      #close \2 group
/       #vi replace with
\1      #paste \1 group in
\&lt;   #replace `<` with it's escaped version
\2      #paste \2 group in
/g      #Do on all occurrences

:%s/\(<text>\n.*\)<\(.*\n.*<\/text>\)/\1\&lt;\2/g
```

The second one is like the first, I've replaced `<` with `>` and `&lt;` with `&gt;`

```
:%s/\(<text>\n.*\)>\(.*\n.*<\/text>\)/\1\&gt;\2/g
```

combine with `|`

```
:%s/\(<text>\n.*\)<\(.*\n.*<\/text>\)/\1\&lt;\2/g | %s/\(<text>\n.*\)>\(.*\n.*<\/text>\)/\1\&gt;\2/g
```

Reference:
[Capturing Groups and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

[Regex without vim escaping](http://regexr.com/3agmd) for `<` part, see the first group is until the `<` mark and the second is right after

Comment: I tried your command in vim. but an error occurred.`E486: Pattern not found: \(<text>\n.*\)<\(.*\n<\/text>\)`. I have no idea how to correct it. I really need your help

Comment: Updated, Add a larger portion of your xml @allenwang

Comment: Yes, I tried, but still `E486: Pattern not found: \(<text>\n.*\)<\(.*\n<\/text>\)`. this problem makes me mad.

Comment: Updated again, test it

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Since I am a newbie in RE, could you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I really appreciate it. The last question, regular expression in vim is different from ordinary regular expression? why do we have to escape '(' in vim command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71839/discussion-between-allenwang-and-shevski).

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex

Answer (score 0):

Not a good situation to be in, really.

However, if you know the valid xml tags in your file, then the following will match only the 'bad tags' you want to escape:

```
<(?!/?grade|/?text)([^>]+)>
```

add more valid tags to that list in the form `|\?tag`.

Then you can substitute with

```
&lt;$1&gt;
```

Here it is on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3agl0).

If you need to do this in vim, then you'll need to translate that into vim regex, which isn't quite the same.

Comment: I only want to escape < and > in <text>tags. But there are thousands of <text> tags in the XML file. I think I have to do it in vim.

Comment: This will do that if you can list the valid tags  you *don't* want to escape. Do you know that?

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. But when I try to search the matching string`<(?!/?grade|/?text)([^>]+)>`. An error occurred, `E486: Pattern not found: <(?!`. Could you please help me with that? I really need your help.