# How to enable "Very magic" mode in vim with vimrc?

Tags: vim

When search something, always typing `\v` is quite boring.
How to write *.vimrc* to make it the default regular expression mode?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760444

Comment: possible duplicate of [In vim, is there a way to set "very magic" permanently and globally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760444/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-set-very-magic-permanently-and-globally)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there is a dedicated setting (like `:set magic`) but I have this line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap / /\v
```

that make every forward search "very magic".

--- EDIT ---

FWIW, I removed that mapping a long time ago as I got used to the default level of magic.

Comment: The idea is not mine, though.

Comment: @hero2008, Don't forget to "accept" this answer if it's what you were looking for.  :)

Comment: **i**noremap /? Maybe `onoremap` or `vnoremap` (I would suggest plain `noremap` because `/` works in all modes covered by it: normal, visual and operator-pending, though first is most used at least by me).

Comment: This clashes when trying to search again using another empty `/` ... which is when it matches everything ...

Comment: Yes, that's the drawback of this method. There's unfortunately no way to have it by default.