# Vim EX command to remove non-duplicate records

Tags: regex, vim

I have a large file which I am trying to reduce to only neighboring duplicated record id lines. (It's been sorted already)

Example:

```
AB12345  10987654321 Andy   Male
AB12345  10987654321 Andrea Female
CD34567  98765432100 Andrea Female
EF45678  54321098765 Bobby  Tables
```

should remove lines 3-4 leaving lines 1-2.

The following regex pattern finds just the duplicate lines successfully, but the subsequent command removes some but not all of the non-matching lines.

```
:/\v^(\a{2}\d{5}\s{2}\d{11}).*\n(\1.*)+
:g!/\v^(\a{2}\d{5}\s{2}\d{11}).*\n(\1.*)+/d
```

Why aren't all the non-matching lines being deleted?

Comment: I have also tried the ex command using `v` in place of `g!`, but the results are the same.

Comment: try with this `:g!/\v^(\a\{2}\d\{5}\s\{2}\d\{11}).*\n(\1.*)\+/d`

Comment: @hawk That deletes everything. The \v modifier sets "very magic" mode negating the need for the extra slashes.

Comment: Unfortunately you  need to escape  special chars with `:global`

Comment: How about `:%!uniq -f 2`?

Comment: @romainl I need to only compare the first two fields. The remaining fields won't necessarily be unique or duplicated.

Comment: Hmm… I misread your question.

Comment: @romainl `-f 2` does the opposite of what the OP asks.  You might try something like this though (the `<(...)` thing is a bashism): `fgrep -f <(awk -v OFS='  ' '{print $1, $2}' data.txt | sort | uniq -d) data.txt`

Comment: Thanks, @lcd047 but it's really the other fields that I need to get the data for. Just getting the IDs won't help much.

Comment: @psaxton Have you run the command?  It does what you ask.  First it gets the duplicated IDs, then it finds the lines in the file matching the IDs.

Comment: Can someone help move this commentversation into a room? I don' have privileges to do that yet.

Comment: @lcd047 I missed the fgrep portion originally. Unfortunately the full command is returning nothing. I have roughly 38000 results with `awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1, $2}' ./data.txt | sort | uniq -d | wc -l` so I'm not sure if that may be the problem.

Comment: `fgrep` is pretty efficient, but `<(...)` is a bashism, and `bash` might have a limit on the relevant buffers.  Try saving the results of `uniq -d` to a temporary file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75964/discussion-between-lcd047-and-psaxton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Vim solution, but this should work:

```
$ fgrep -f <(awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1, $2}' data.txt | sort | uniq -d) data.txt
```

The `<(...)` is a bashism, and `OSF='  '` has exactly two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "magic" version of `:global`
Possible solutions: escape special characters as this
`:g!/^(\a\{2}\d\{5}\s\{2}\d\{11}).*\n(\1.*)\+/d`.

You can always reuse previous find pattern, and use it like this `g://d`

Extra links

- [very magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760444/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-set-very-magic-permanently-and-globally/23021259#23021259)
- [Simplifying regular expressions using magic and no-magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic)